# How to modify xml file and save the changes using libxml2 in C?

Tags: c, linux, libxml2

The value is not updated in the actual xml file. How to make the changes updated in the xml file? Thanks.

```
xmlTextReader *xmlReaderPtr = NULL;
xmlNodePtr curNode;

xmlReaderPtr = xmlReaderForFd(fd, NULL, NULL, XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS);
curNode      = xmlTextReaderCurrentNode(xmlReaderPtr);
xmlNodeSetContent(curNode, "value");
```

Answer (score 0):

With a streaming API like *xmlreader*, you can only parse documents. If you want to modify and write a document, use the "normal" non-streaming API to read a whole document (`xmlDoc`) into memory (using [`xmlParseFile`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlParseFile), [`xmlReadFile`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlReadFile), etc.), make the required changes, then write the document using [`xmlDocDump`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlDocDump).

To locate the nodes that you want to change, the [XPath API](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xpath.html) is useful. Have a look at the [`xpath2.c` example code](http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/xpath2.c) and the [other examples](http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/).